# PHP posting <a href> causes error on insert

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a php file that takes values from a form and posts them to a mysql database. One of the table fields is a button link to a video that will play when clicked. It works great if I go into the database and manually add the link. However my PHP insert causes an error. Please have a look at this code:

```
$fileName = "video_".$id.".html";
$link = "<a href=\"javascript: void(0)\" onclick=\"MM_openBrWindow('videos/".$fileName."','','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=420,height=390')\"><button class=\"count\">Watch Video</button></a>";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","videomanager","password","my_database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$sql="INSERT INTO video_list (date, title, description, link) VALUES('$_POST[date]','".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['sermon'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['description'])."','$link' )";
if (!mysqli_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
  }
  echo "This video has been successfully added to the video database.";
mysqli_close($con);
```

If I look at $link by doing something like: echo $link; die(); it produces a page with the button and the code in the button looks good. Is it how I am trying to insert it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: The problem is the `'` inside `$link` - escape them!

Comment: View your source and you'll see what the `href`'s output is. You can then pinpoint where the bad quotes are.

Comment: Have you tried putting `mysqli_real_escape_string` around `$link` as well?

Comment: The error message just says "Error:" No message from the database. I have tried putting the escape string around $link... same result. Kingkero, I didn't think you had to escape single quotes.

Comment: funny. they're the most disabling amongst characters in queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a lot of errors

```
<?php
$fileName = "video_".$id.".html";
$link     = "<a href=\"javascript: void(0)\" onclick=\"MM_openBrWindow('videos/".$fileName."','','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=420,height=390')\"><button class=\"count\">Watch Video</button></a>";
$con      = mysqli_connect("localhost","videomanager","password","my_database");

// Check connection
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() )
    die('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );

// Check param is set
if( !isset($_POST['date'], $_POST['sermon'], $_POST['description']) )
    die('Param Error');

// SQL Request
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO video_list (date, title, description, link) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s')",
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['date']), 
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['sermon']),
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['description']), 
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $link) 
);

// SQL execute
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));

// Free result
mysqli_free_result($result);

// Close connection
mysqli_close($con);

echo "This video has been successfully added to the Kim Watt videos.";
```

Comment: Meaning that it's always best for not only the OP to know where the errors were made, but could prove to be beneficial for others who may visit this question/answer. @nigro.simone - If no information is told where the error was made and to simply copy/paste code and hope/wish that it will work, then nothing has been learned/known. I for one, would need to compare the OP's code and your answer, to know where the changes were made, that resulted in a solution. ;-)

Comment: I actually learned a lot from this. This site and the people here are beyond cool. Thanks!

Comment: @fred-ii, I understand, but unfortunately my bad english does not allow me to explain complex

Comment: Your English seems very good so far ;-) But I understand. If at all possible, do put in an explanation, or at least point out where the mistake was made. I.e.: *"Your quotes in (this code) needed to be (this)"* type of thing. Cheers @nigro.simone